# get the real net_device under the bridge at layer 4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Our scenario is as follow: When the TCP connection is established (we can check this in `tcp_set_state()` function), we can find out the egress `net_device` of this connection via `sk->sk_dst_cache->dev`. With this `net_device` we can distinguish our `net_device` with other `net_device` on the system.

This approach failed when the egress device is a sub-interface of a bridge, because `sk->sk_dst_cache->dev` always points to the bridge. Is it possible to get the real `net_device` (`struct net_bridge_port`) under the bridge if we are currently at Layer 4.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `struct net_bridge` has a list of member ports, `port_list`. The list contains `struct net_bridge_port` elements, which in turn contain the `struct net_dev`.

You can get the `struct net_bridge` from the `struct net_device` of the bridge trivially:

```
struct net_bridge *br = netdev_priv(dev);
```

Of course, that still doesn't tell you which of the member interfaces the packet came in on, but not knowing anything about *why* you're trying to do this I can't say if that's a problem or not.

Comment: Hi @Kristof Provost, Thank a lot for your opinion. Is it possible to find out the exact egress interface that  the packet will be transmitted. Our network device can do TCP connection offload, so we want to distinguish this device with other normal net_device (wireless interfaces)

Comment: In that case I rather wonder if it's worth trying to make this work. I'd be inclined to say that your device should simply refuse to be part of a bridge (set IFF_DONT_BRIDGE in priv_flags), or simply don't offload the TCP connection in that case. Alternatively you can patch the bridge code to give you access to the internals so you can run __br_fdb_get yourself and figure out the destination interface. Down that road lies a twisty maze of timeouts and race conditions though. In short, you'd be breaking the layering model quite badly, with bad results.

Comment: Thank @Kristof Provost. Do you think that we can move the established connection detection to elsewhere? Inside the device driver is not a good choice, because it will consume a lot effort to track this establish connection.

Comment: You can take a look at one of the solutions proposed back in the 2.6.14 days: http://lwn.net/Articles/147289/. Bear in mind that this was shot down by the kernel community for a variety of reasons. All in all I'd expect a generic TOE solution to still suffer from the same drawbacks, but perhaps you're focusing on a specific subset which could be more acceptable. I've certainly seen network offload engines do good work in embedded systems, but they were limited to forwarded traffic.